# How to make multiple scatter subplots with sharing one-axis?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

| date | name | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | harry | 100 |
| 1 | joe | 20 |
| 2 | harry | 50 |
| 3 | joe | 60 |
| 3 | lee | 25 |
| 4 | lee | 60 |
| 4 | harry | 200 |
| 4 | joe | 90 |

I was trying to share 'date' axis (x-axis) with 432 person name. Image was too large to show.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dec=pd.read_csv('december.csv')
sns.lmplot(x='date', y='amount',
           data= dec, fit_reg=False, hue='name', legend=True, palette='Set1')
```

This code is giving one graph with 432 hue. But I want 432 graphs. How to do it?

Comment: Please see how to ask a StackOverflow Question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . For `pandas` specifically, plerase include sample input data (no images), code you have tried and expected output. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: you are going to want to use seaborn for this. Look into `catplot` (https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) or `relplot` (https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html) in the seaborn library. Here is an example line of code from the documentaiton: `sns.relplot(data=tips, x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="day", col="time")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the same code you wrote, but instead of putting `hue='name'`, you put `col='name'` and it should give you the expected behavior:

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dec = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [1,'harry',100],
        [1,'joe',20],
        [2,'harry',50],
        [3,'joe',60],
        [3,'lee',25],
        [4,'lee',60],
        [4,'harry',200],
        [4,'joe',90],        
    ],
    columns=['date','name','amount'],
)

sns.lmplot(
    x='date',
    y='amount',
    data= dec,
    fit_reg=False,
    col='name',
    legend=True,
    palette='Set1',
)
```

[image]

If you want to break the rows, you can define a column wrapper with `col_wrap` (number of plots per row):

```py
sns.lmplot(
    x='date',
    y='amount',
    data= dec,
    fit_reg=False,
    col='name',
    col_wrap=1,
    legend=True,
    palette='Set1',
)
```

[image]

EDIT: using the `groupby()` method, you can easily get aggregates such as number of dots per plot and total amount per group.
The main idea is to group the records in the `dec` dataframe by name (has it was implicitly done in the plot above).

Continuing on the code above, you can have a preview of the `groupby` operation using the `describe` method:

```py
dec.groupby('name').describe()

Out[2]: 
       date                                                amount                                                          
      count      mean       std  min   25%  50%   75%  max  count        mean        std   min    25%    50%     75%    max
name                                                                                                                       
harry   3.0  2.333333  1.527525  1.0  1.50  2.0  3.00  4.0    3.0  116.666667  76.376262  50.0  75.00  100.0  150.00  200.0
joe     3.0  2.666667  1.527525  1.0  2.00  3.0  3.50  4.0    3.0   56.666667  35.118846  20.0  40.00   60.0   75.00   90.0
lee     2.0  3.500000  0.707107  3.0  3.25  3.5  3.75  4.0    2.0   42.500000  24.748737  25.0  33.75   42.5   51.25   60.0
```

Using the pandas `groupby` method, we group records by `'name'` and pick any column (here: `'amount'`) to get the count (the count is the same aggregate for each column, as it counts each individual occurence of each different `'name'`):

```py
counts = dec.groupby('name')['amount'].count()
counts

Out[3]: 
name
harry    3
joe      3
lee      2
Name: amount, dtype: int64
```

To get the total amount, we do the same, we pick the `'amount'` column and call the `sum()` method instead of the `count()` method:

```py
total_amounts = dec.groupby('name')['amount'].sum()
total_amounts

Out[4]: 
name
harry    350
joe      170
lee       85
Name: amount, dtype: int64
```

We now have two series indexed by `'name'` containing the information we want: `counts` and `total_amounts`.
We're gonna use these two series to build a title for each subplot:

```py
plot = sns.lmplot(
    x='date',
    y='amount',
    data=dec,
    fit_reg=False,
    col='name',
    legend=True,
    palette='Set1',
)

for name in plot.axes_dict:
    sublot_title = f'name = {name}, number of dots = {counts[name]}, total amount = {total_amounts[name]}'
    plot.axes_dict[name].set_title(sublot_title)

plot.fig
```

It prints:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! @apaolilo What if I also want to show number of counts with the name?

Comment: by "number of counts", do you mean the sum of the `amount` value for each name? Or the number of times it occurs in the dataframe (number of dots on each subplot)?

Comment: @apaolilo Could you please tell me how to do both?

Comment: @ShashwatAwasthi I edited the answer to explain how to do both